# My problem is that the Android build is executed in Docker until it gets stuck for the second time

Tags: android, docker

Currently my Docker is installed on my own computer, the computer is 16G, every time the container is created for the first time, the first execution of ./gradlew assembleDebug is OK, but after the second re-pull code, then gradlew has been stuck Stayed, and I don't know why, docker is stuck. At this time, other software is normal, and there is no computer stuck in the whole, but all the commands such as docker ps are not available. My build script looks like this:

```sh
if [ ! -d /opt/build/MyProject ];then
  cd /opt/build/
  git clone [project git address]
fi
cd /opt/build/MyProject
git reset --hard
git fetch --all
git checkout $Branch_Name
git pull
cd /opt/build/MyProject
./gradlew assemble$Build_Type
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put some logs to find out second time at which command script is stuck. It could be some threads already running of previous runs or stuck long time.

eg: you can check before assemble step status with "gradlew tasks".

So, put logs at each step to narrow down the potential cause in the second run.

Br,
Deepak